# Переписать правило htaccess для apache под nginx

Tags: .htaccess, apache, nginx, веб-сервер, watermark

Был написан скрипт для наложения водяного знака на изображения, работал он в связке с файлом .htaccess, который перенаправлял картинки из каталога на скрипт:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php 

<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png)$"> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /watermark/watermark.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L,QSA] 
</FilesMatch>
```

Все работало, но в какой-то момент перестало работать, на вопросы хостер отвечает тем, что хостинг работает под управлением apache + nginx, правило написано для apache, а всю статику обрабатывает nginx.

Придумано для того, чтобы снизить нагрузку на сервер. Почему раньше работало - хз. Можно ли переписать это правило под nginx, чтобы функциональность ватермарка сохранилась?!

Comment: Вы не можете управлять nginx на хостинге. Вам его настройки недоступны.

Comment: Хостер предоставил доступы к конфигам nginx!!!

Comment: Это более чем странно. Выложите их сюда тогда.

Comment: Доступы выложить?)))) вот что хостер ответил: Вы процитировали ответ на Ваш вопрос: Вы можете перевести Ваш сайт в ручной режим настройки, после чего файлы конфигурации веб-сервера станут Вам доступны для редактирования в папке ~/etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

Перевод сайты в ручной режим осуществляется в меню "Сайты" - имя сайта - "Настройки" - "Веб-сервер" панели управления хостингом.

Comment: Не доступы конечно, а файлы настроек nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нет, «переписать» невозможно. ведь функциональность файла `.htaccess` — это исключительный «костыль» программы *apache*.

скорее всего, в вашем случае наиболее рациональным будет вообще убрать программу *nginx* — если большая часть запросов к статическим файлам исчерпывается файлами с суффиксами `.gif`, `.png` или `.jpg`, то нет смысла держать посредника в виде этой программы.

если посредник всё-таки необходим (или от него невозможно избавиться, например, из-за ограничений вашего хостера), то в конфигурацию программы *nginx* надо внести изменение, исключающее файлы с упомянутыми суффиксами из списка обрабатываемых программой.

---

например, если у вас в конфигурации *nginx* для вашего сайта имеется подобная конструкция (взято из первой попавшейся в интернете инструкции):

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|js)$ {
  root /var/www/mysite.ru;
}
```

то просто уберите из неё те суффиксы, файлы с которыми должны обрабатываться программой *apache*:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|js)$ {
  root /var/www/mysite.ru;
}
```

программу *nginx* после этого надо будет перезапустить.